# Input email doest register a value after dot in angular forms

Tags: html, angular, forms

i have a problem creating a form that validates an email. I am using a regex validation, but none of the emails passed. I noted that the value of the email input doesnt register a value after one dot.

Example: email@gmail.com
`form.get(field)!.value` returns email@gmail.

This is my form, with angular reactive forms

```
  public userForm = this.fb.group({
    email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3), Validators.pattern(this.validationService.emailPattern)], []] })
```

This is the html input

```
          <input formControlName="email" type="email" class="form-control"  placeholder="Ingresa tu email">
```

I feel like I'm making a silly mistake, but i cant find the error

Comment: Show your emailPattern

Comment: ```public emailPattern = /\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/```. But i dont think the problem is the pattern, because the input doesnt detect the complete value

Comment: minimal reproducible example needed - validators shouldn't be changing the control value